arcgis-js-api Renderer not working as before
I have a vanilla js application where I let the user 'configure' his own arcade expression using an interface. I use this arcade expression in order to scale the layer differently depending on the view scale.
Consider the following arcade expression (for testing):
var scale = When(
                  $view.scale >= 144447, 1,
                  $view.scale >= 72223 && $view.scale < 144447, 10,
                  $view.scale >= 36111 && $view.scale < 72223, 1,
                  $view.scale >= 18055 && $view.scale < 36111, 10,
                  $view.scale >= 9027 && $view.scale < 18055, 1,
                  $view.scale >= 4513 && $view.scale < 9027, 10,
                  $view.scale >= 2256 && $view.scale < 4513, 1,
                  $view.scale >= 1128 && $view.scale < 2256, 10,
                  10
                   );
return scale;

For testing purposes, I just modified the layer's renderer to use this expression:
layer.renderer.visualVariables[0].valueExpression = arcadeExp;

This code works well on version 4.28, but not on 4.29 or 4.30.
I tried using method from createVisualVariables and createContinuousRenderer and many other ways, but none of them works on 4.29, just on 4.28.
The only way I could achieve this was to refresh the layer manually using layer.refresh() when the scale changed.
